# xml data to chart resets? upon new data

Tags: c#, charts

so everytime this runs through

```
OpenFileDialog xmlOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
xmlOpenFileDialog.Filter = @"XML|*.xml";
xmlOpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
//Start
//Implement a way for user to have last opened file shown if program is closed by accident?
//xmlOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
//End
xmlOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
DialogResult userClickedOk = xmlOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();

if (userClickedOk == DialogResult.OK)
{
    lastKnownFileName = xmlOpenFileDialog.FileName;
    System.IO.Stream filestream = xmlOpenFileDialog.OpenFile();

    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream))
    {
        UpChart_Chart.Serializer.IsResetWhenLoading = false;
        UpChart_Chart.Serializer.Content = SerializationContents.Data;

        UpChart_Chart.Serializer.SerializableContent += ",DataPoint.AxisLabel,DataPoint.Label,Series.AxisLabels,Series.Name,Series.ChartType,ChartChartArea.Name";

        UpChart_Chart.Serializer.Load(reader);
    }
```

then the data we have in the chart resets when new inputs happens?
how do we make sure that the data we have is correctly put in the right areas?